# Keep getting C2664 error - cannot convert argument from char[10] to char

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference, c2664

I keep getting an C2664 error, "cannot convert argument 1 from char[10] to char" when I attempt to compile and run.  I've tried replacing arrays with pointers (char answer[] to char * answers).  I can do this without passing arrays to a function, but that's what I'm trying to work on getting better at.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
bool grade(char, char, int, int&, int&);
int goodbye();

int main()
{
    const int TEST_LENGTH = 10;
    char const correctAnswers[TEST_LENGTH] =
    { 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D' };
    char studentAnswers[TEST_LENGTH] = {};
    int correct = 0, missed = 0;
    bool passing;

    cout << "Welcome to your Driver's License Exam." << endl;
    cout << "This test is ten multiple choice questions." << endl;
    cout << "Only A, B, C, and D are valid answers." << endl;
    cout << "Please begin.";

    for (int i=0; i < TEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        int errorCount = 0;
        cout << "Question " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> studentAnswers[i];
        studentAnswers[i] = toupper(studentAnswers[i]);
        while (studentAnswers[i] < 'A' || studentAnswers[i] > 'D')
        {
            if (errorCount++ > 3)
                goodbye();
            cout << "Only A, B, C, and D are valid input. Reenter. " << endl;
            cout << "Question " << i + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> studentAnswers[i];
        }
    }

    passing = grade(studentAnswers, correctAnswers, TEST_LENGTH, correct, missed);

    if (passing) 
    {
        cout << "Congratulations!" << endl;
        cout << "You have passed the exam." << endl;
        cout << "Total number of correct answers: " << correct << endl;
        cout << "Total number of incorrect answer: " << missed << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "You have failed the exam" << endl;
        cout << "Sorry, you have not passed the exam." << correct << endl;
        cout << "Total number of incorrect answer: " << missed << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}

bool grade(char answers[], const char key[], const int size, int& hits, int & misses)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++ )
    {
        if (answers[i] == key[i])
            hits++;
        else
            misses++;
    }

    if (hits >= 8)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int goodbye() 
{
    cout << "GOOD BYE" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Definition and declaration of `grade` are different.

Answer (score 0):

Your function prototype doesn't match your declaration:

```
//Prototype, takes two chars as first params
bool grade(char, char, int, int&, int&); 

//Declaration, takes two char-arrays (pointers to char) as first params
bool grade(char answers[], const char key[], const int size, int& hits, int & misses)
```

Change your prototype to match your declaration and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool grade(char, char, int, int&, int&);
```

and

```
bool grade(char answers[], const char key[], const int size, int& hits, int & misses)
```

See the difference? This is a case where the compiler error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. You just need to learn to see clearly the code that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function prototype:

```
//Function prototypes
bool grade(char*,const char*, const int, int, int);
```

instead of:

```
//Function prototypes
bool grade(char, char, int, int&, int&);
```

should do the tricks. Short TIP: 
checking the output of the compiler error would lead you also to the answer: e.g

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
```